# How to get YouTube thumbnail image aspect ratio to be 21:9

Tags: sass, youtube, bem

```html
<link href="https://www1.chester.ac.uk/sites/all/themes/global/css/app_chester.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="background: #eaeaea">
  <div class="column row">
    <div class="m-modal-video__column m-modal-video__column--primary">
     <div class="m-modal-video m-modal-video--primary-full-width">
      <div class="m-cta__vcenter"><h3 style="color: black; text-align: center;">Be Part of It</h3>
        <p style="color: black; text-align: center;">Choose an innovative degree that has been designed with your employability at its core.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="m-modal-video__column m-modal-video__column--secondary">
    <div class="m-modal-video m-modal-video--primary-full-width">
      <div class="m-cta__vcenter">
        <div class="m-modal-video__container m-modal-video__container--cinemascope" data-open="youtubemodal">
          <a><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ily454tCpWE/maxresdefault.jpg">
            <div class="m-modal-video__overlay m-modal-video__overlay--triangle">
              <div class="m-modal-video m-modal-video__triangle"></div>
            </div></a>
          </div>
          <div class="reveal large" id="youtubemodal" data-reveal data-reset-on-close="true">
            <div class="m-video m-video--modal m-video--cinemascope"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ily454tCpWE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
            <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've got a modal on my site, and use the following to display a thumbnail image:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/DxwrdB7A6-I/maxresdefault.jpg
```

The problem is the video has an aspect ratio of 21:9. I've used the following styles, but still get the black letterbox on both the top and bottom of the image.  Is there a way to just display the YouTube thumbnail without the black letterbox?

```
&__container {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 42.85714%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    a img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a runnable code snippet here? It looks like YouTube produced a cropped 16:9 thumbnail for your video and you're stretching it to fit a 21:9 container, so I'm not sure where letterboxing is coming from. If you let us see the problem in action, we can fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've got enough points/experience (whatever it's called) to post a code snippet.  Is it just a case of using codepen or something similar?

Comment: It's the button on the editing toolbar to the right of the image icon. I don't believe there's any sort of requirements needed to use the feature.

Comment: I've added the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your sample code to add two new CSS rules to correspond to a class your HTML already had with no styles:

`.m-modal-video__container--cinemascope` defines the container around your cinemascope-ratio image, using the `padding-bottom` trick you'd previously tried implementing.

`.m-modal-video__container--cinemascope img` defines the sizing and positioning of the image inside the above container. Knowing you want this image to maintain its aspect ratio and not stretch, I've removed the `height: 100%` rule (so the height is automatically calculated) and vertically centered the image with the `top: 50%` and  `transform: translateY(-50%)` trick.

This is all needed because YouTube still produced a 16:9 JPG thumbnail for your video despite its 21:9 ratio, so we're essentially using this trick to hide the black bars in the image. I still see a tiny sliver poking through, but you slightly adjust your `padding-bottom` ratio if you were worried about that, or increase your `img`'s `width` past 100%.

```css
.m-modal-video__container--cinemascope {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 42.85714%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.m-modal-video__container--cinemascope img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www1.chester.ac.uk/sites/all/themes/global/css/app_chester.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="background: #eaeaea">
  <div class="column row">
    <div class="m-modal-video__column m-modal-video__column--secondary">
      <div class="m-modal-video m-modal-video--primary-full-width">
        <div class="m-cta__vcenter">
          <div class="m-modal-video__container m-modal-video__container--cinemascope" data-open="youtubemodal">
            <a><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ily454tCpWE/maxresdefault.jpg">
              <div class="m-modal-video__overlay m-modal-video__overlay--triangle">
                <div class="m-modal-video m-modal-video__triangle"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="reveal large" id="youtubemodal" data-reveal data-reset-on-close="true">
            <div class="m-video m-video--modal m-video--cinemascope"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ily454tCpWE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
            <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @snarf1974 Happy to help! Also, for future reference you should isolate the problem in HTML and CSS (and JS if needed) in your snippet here rather than linking to an external CSS file. We only need to look at the relevant part of the problem, and your links could change or go down at some point, thus rendering examples like this broken to future users.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know, will make sure to isolate any problems in the future